# PHP/Javascript: See if someone is visiting the same url

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, angularjs, laravel

I have a project built in Laravel with AngularJS where you can view and edit a report.
I want to implement the feature that when someone is editing the report, no one else should be allowed to do the same. It should be locked while someone is editing it. 
When the user is done editing it or leaves the page, the report should open up for anyone to edit it again.

What are your recommendations for this? I've thought a little bit about cookies/sessions, but I'm not sure how to detect if the user leaves the page.

Comment: You'd need to implement some checkout/checkin mechanism on the server. This has little to do with Angular, and in any case too broad.

Comment: add a timestamp field to the report and update that timestamp via ajax every say 30 seconds. then for every user who wants to work on that report check if that report has a timestamp that is newer as say one or two minutes.

Comment: @NewDev with some tatic code that locks the report when you click on say "edit report" and then unlocks that report when you click on "release report" or "save report" or something similar you run into the proiblem that the user might close his window or just navigate somewhere else. that case might lock the report for good

Comment: @ITroubs, yes :) that's why I added "too broad", because what if the intent is to checkout like in SharePoint - it just stays checked out to a particular user until hell freezes over.

Comment: @NewDev haha yes =) but I think my short suggestion I first made should be a good pointer into the right direction that narrows it down a bit ;-)

Comment: @ITroubs, no arguments from me :)

Comment: @ITroubs: Thanks but that solution seems a bit heavy to me. Hitting the database every 30 seconds would require a more accurate result to make me feel good about it...

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best way is to use websockets. Report editing will create websocket connection with your server and when editing page will closed, connection will be terminated

Comment: Haven't worked with websockets before but i definitely seems like a good solution from the things I've read so far. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Mattias a websocket approach is similar to my approach since you still have to somehow handle the locking of the report. websockets do NOT solve that problem. they merely replace the 30 second timeouted ajax with something that permanently runs in the browser and does requests to your server (depending on the implementation you chose it might do requests or do some other request through a certain port. that might result in even more hits to the database)

Comment: Good info, thanks. I need to do more research on this, maybe I'll end up using your solution in the end.